# Can server snapshots potentially damage MySQL transactions?

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, snapshot, database-restore

Let's say your taking daily snapshots of your server as a whole (public_html, sql files, etc) for later restoration in case of system failure.

Is it possible that you can restore damaged a MySQL InnoDB if you took the snapshot while an uncommitted transaction was taking place? Or will InnoDB do just fine and discard "incomplete" transactions on restoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the databases viewpoint we are dealing with an unclean shutdown (i.e. power went off) and a lost connection so it will discard all transactions that are not committed.

If you are taking a snapshot of the server that's just like freezing everything in a cryogenic sleep, then after a restore the database would just awake expecting to talk to a non existing application.

The only issue that i can see is not from a transaction itself but from the fact that the database itself resides inside files. What if you freeze a file half-written to disk. I can see how that might be a problem. On the other hand there's probably some architectural design in place to prevent this as the same is true for a power outage and a database should live through that too.

Answer (score 0):

To best of my knowledge, during a transaction, nothing gets saved into the database until commit has occurred. That's the ACID compliance right there. So no database files get written during a transaction, only after.

Also, in my opinion, database 'snapshots' should be done via dump. I'm not a server administrator so I wouldn't know for a fact, but it'd be a lot safer to restore the data that way.

Although, MySQL is a gray area to me, I'm more confident with SQL Server, so don't take this as a fact, as SQL Server has its own ways of getting backups made.

Comment: Does this mean that on-going transactions only reside in "memory" or "session" of some sort? I was under the impression some temporary data is written somewhere in the DB, at least not in the actual tables until commit. I understand that dump is a better way but I like to know the behavior of MySQL InnoDB in restoring from a whole server "snapshot".